# Cypress: Looping through blog posts [cy.click()` failed because this element is detached from the DOM]

Tags: cypress

I am trying to traverse a blog site, click on each article, once the page loads, assert a few values, go back and then repeat for the next article. There is a total of 10 articles I wish to traverse. Upon doing so, I am getting a DOM detached error. Code and error below:

```
cy.get('main[id="main"]>article>header a').each(($el, index, $list) => {
  cy.wrap($el).click({ force: true });
  
  // perform some assertions here on the page
  // ...

  cy.go(-1); // go back to parent page, rinse and repeat until all articles are done
});
```

Error:

```
     CypressError: `cy.click()` failed because this element is detached from the DOM.

Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.

The previous command that ran was:

  > `cy.wrap()`

This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current command.

Common situations why this happens:
  - Your JS framework re-rendered asynchronously
  - Your app code reacted to an event firing and removed the element

You typically need to re-query for the element or add 'guards' which delay Cypress from running new commands.

https://on.cypress.io/element-has-detached-from-dom at ensureAttached
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've seen this on another question, simply repeat the query inside the loop and you will avoid all detachment errors.

```js
const selector = 'main[id="main"]>article>header a';
cy.get(selector)
  .each(($el, index) => {
    cy.get(selector).eq(index).click();
    cy.url().should('eq', 'abc')
    cy.go('back')
})
```